# How to Allow Client-Service to Build Complex Object in WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, interop

I made a simple PasteBin demo example of what my code looks like: http://pastebin.com/GpDhPRVm

My actual `Process` object is extremely complex that includes adding collections of Tasks, Documents, Workflows, etc into a `Process` object and setting properties through methods, etc.

My [PasteBin example](http://pastebin.com/GpDhPRVm) is as simple as I can make it to show where things break down.  Including the `Process` object in the `CreateNewProcess` method in my service (shown in code below), allows the service user to automatically "see" the `Process` object, properties and enumerators in their instance on the client side.

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ICreateProcess

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub CreateNewProcess(ByVal newprocess As Process)

End Interface
```

However, it does not allow them to use any of the methods like the 'AddTask' method ([shown in PasteBin example](http://pastebin.com/GpDhPRVm)) and it also doesn't expose the `Task` or `TaskCollection` objects.  Even if I decorate the methods with `DataContract`, `OperationContract`, etc they still are not visible to the client service.

**This is my major issue:**  I need the client service to be able to fully "build" the `Process` object and then pass it in to the `CreateNewProcess` method.

*Another small note:* (to avoid comments asking me about it) is that I made sure that all of my properties are simple types that are interoperable since this needs to be able to work for Java - not just .NET clients.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out with a little help from a buddy of mine.

Can't use methods at all outside the .svc service class; only properties, enums and sub objects will translate down to the client.  (I figured this)

Then, instead of using a `Collection`, you have to use a generic `List` type.

So, instead of this:

```
    Public Tasks As New TaskCollection() 'where TaskCollection inherits from Collection
```

I needed to do this:

```
    Public Tasks As List(Of Task)
```

And the client will just have to build their own array of Tasks and assign it to the t.Tasks property.

This works like a charm now: http://pastebin.com/rt8HwsXY